# How can I make Java3D start faster?

Tags: java, optimization, java-3d

My application takes several seconds to show the first window with a `Canvas3D` in it. I've profiled it and found that the bottleneck is in `SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration()`; the first call takes three or four seconds, and it *must* be called before the scene can be rendered.

I'm using the Direct3D renderer (`-Dj3d.rend=d3d`), because the OpenGL renderer crashes on my graphics card. I have an integrated ATI card running a single monitor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for the slowdown is that `GraphicsDevice.getConfigurations()`, which is used by `SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration()`, is very slow on some systems. See [this java.net forum thread](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=56947&tstart=0), which links to [this Java3D bug](https://java3d.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=406), which in turn links to [this Sun bug](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=56947&tstart=0):

> The problem is that `::DescribePixelFormat` Win32 call is slow - takes
>   up to 60ms to complete.
>   ...
>   With the suggested workaround (which elminats [sic] the offending win32 calls)
>   the time is significantly improved (to, like, 0ms).

The workaround mentioned is to **pass `-Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true` to the JVM**, which makes the underlying native code not call `DescribePixelFormat`.

This apparently is not a perfect solution:

> ... some 
>   applications which use OpenGL with Java may not work correctly.

But since I was using Direct3D anyway, it's not a problem. **This cut 3.2 seconds off of the startup time.**

Comment: I just found this workaround yesterday, so I'm making a public record so I won't lose it again.

Comment: How to pass -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true to jvm? or How to stop calling Graphics Configuration object in java3D ?